# Tag synonym request: [my-site] -> [my-sites]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

Hope this is the correct way to deal with this kind of issue (a quick search on meta-stackexchange seems to confirm this).

I would suggest to add a tag synonym for [my-site] -> [my-sites] (but don't have the rep to). Seems there are multiple questions that uses both tag, and I can't see a real difference between the two.

Anyone can open the synonym request? Or should we delete the [my-sites] tag (only 22 question, we should be able to switch the tags manually if we have to)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have merged [my-sites](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-sites) into [my-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-site)

Comment: Perfect. Any indication or preferred way to act if I spot anything similar in the future? another topic like this will do?

Comment: Yea meta is best. :)